# default gateway the same as my domain cotrollers ip?

Tags: ip, domain-controller

What should I make my default gateway for my Domain Controller? Should it be the same as its IP address or something else?

Answer (score 8):

It should be the same IP address as your gateway for the subnet that your domain controller is on.

If you don't know what this means, you should run far away from your computer and hire someone that knows what they are doing. Gateways are an elementary networking principle.

Comment: yes thanks for pointing that out and being a complete jerk. I'm still in school and just wanted to double check before I messed something up.

Comment: @MDL - If you had read the [faq], you'd see that this is a site for `system administrators and desktop support professionals.` When you ask a question, it is assumed that you're in a production environment unless otherwise stated. Sorry if you took offense to this, but you might be putting the chicken before the egg. Active Directory is fairly complicated. You should get a handle on basic networking concepts before you work your way up. The principles build on each other.

Answer (score 3):

Completely agree with MarkM, hire a professional, but in the spirit of amusing myself:

A Default Gateway is a Router (or simulation of a router) that will be sent all network data for networks that are not on the local subnet.

For example the local subnet: 192.168.0.1 / 255.255.255.0 
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.5

All data sent from the computer to any 192.168.0.x address will go out on the local network interface.

All data sent to any other address (for example 192.168.1.10) will be forwarded to the Default Gateway (192.168.0.5) for forwarding onto the appropriate network link that can access the 192.168.1.x subnet.

Comment: Good definition, but you people could have been more nice when explaining it. I didn't think that belittling someone was a requirement in order to answer a question.

Comment: There was no intent to belittle. As per MarkM, the forum is for, and we assume you're in, a production environment. The question showed you're not experienced enough to manage a product environment, which is highly concerning to us.